# Jetty Grails store files folder in production

Tags: grails, jetty

The code below works in my local(dev):

```
f.transferTo(new File("/home/ubuntu/save/data-comp/" + f.getOriginalFilename()))
```

But in my jetty app (prod), the file isn't storing in the folder i gave above(which exists), and whenever I want to retrieve, this error appear to me:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/save/data-comp/abc.txt (No such file or directory)
```

My question is: What is the way to store file in production to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like permission problem to me. Make sure the dir is writable by the jetty-user

Comment: Can you verbose your answer? I'm trying to configure it on this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty-Policy#How_do_I_start_JettyPolicy.3F)

Comment: I'm not a linux expert. All I know is, that usually you start a server with a specific user. Tomcat for example is started with tomcat user. For Jetty it should be the same. That means, that the jetty user should be able to read/write the files/directories you want it to read. 
For that you should be using `chown` command

Comment: I granted the folder `chmod -R 777 /folder` . it worked, thanks